# Hide ribbon group title

Tags: 2013, ribbon, grouping

How to hide the group title in a server ribbon tab?

I've seen a picture of a ribbon without group titles, but removing the group title or just leaving it blank, produces a nerfed layout, which look like this:

[image: Ribbon nerfed layout]

I customized the server ribbon following this tutorial http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html

The sharepoint version I am testing it on is 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the group title needs to be specified in order for sharepoint to work correctly. But a grouptitle can be hidden via css. The class responsible for the group title is "ms-cui-groupTitle". 
So in css we hide it wit the following command:

```
.ms-cui-groupTitle {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

This way the group title exists, but it is invisible.

UPDATE:

The visibility attribute hides the group title, but leaves a blank space there. Using "display: none" the entire ribbon is nerfed, and does not work correctly.

So to overcome both issues, the ribbon needs to be scaled. This is done by adding height definitions to .ms-cui-tabContainer and #s4-ribbonrow

```
.ms-cui-tabContainer {
    height: 60px;
}

body #s4-ribbonrow {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

This way, the ribbon is rendered perfectly

The downside of this is that it scales the other tabs. In my case it scaled the "PAGE" tab to this:

[image: Shrinked ribbon tab]

Which is actually not bad. 
To overcome this the heights must be defined based on the tab id, so the other tabs will not shrink.